# how do I link a button to a spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am trying to make an app in which there will be a spinner with several values. A button will print that value in a text holder.

But, as you can see in the code bellow, the program cannot resolve the symbols "Teste1" and "Teste2".

```
Spinner merendas;

    String[] morfes = {"Teste1","Teste2"};

    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;

    merendas = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.merendas);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,morfes);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    merendas.setAdapter(adapter);

    merendas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long morfes) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        morfes = Teste1;
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        morfes = Teste2;
                        break;
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you tell me what is test1 and test2? its string variable or string which you want to show in spinner items?

Comment: To access Teste1 and Teste2 you will have to access it from the array morfes like morfes[0] and morfes[1]

Comment: Teste1 and Teste2 are strings, not variables. They are exactly what you will see in the spinner.

If I change Teste1 and Teste2 for morfes[0] and morfes[1] it says "array type expected, found long".

Comment: Hello @Skwead the Teste1 and Teste2 are long not String. So you should do like this morfes[0] = String.valueOf(Teste1) and morfes[1] = String.valueOf(Teste2)

Comment: If I change "Teste1" and "Teste2" for those you suggested, the errors are kept: morfes[1] and [2] are expected to be long and Teste1 and 2 are not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A button will print that value in a text holder.

If you want to print which spinner item is selected , You **`don't need setOnItemSelectedListener()`** for your spinner.

You can simply use

```
String selected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
yourtextview.setText(selected);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not doing it yet.
The point now is to figure out what is wrong with the spinner itself, I have not eve added the other components